# Mysql trigger not working on update query

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a Mysql table for weekly attendance..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students_attendance` (
  `student_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `month` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `w1` ENUM ('Absent', 'Present', 'Leave') NULL,
  `w2` ENUM ('Absent', 'Present', 'Leave') NULL,
  `w3` ENUM ('Absent', 'Present', 'Leave') NULL,
  `w4` ENUM ('Absent', 'Present', 'Leave') NULL,
  `w5` ENUM ('Absent', 'Present', 'Leave') NULL,
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`, `month`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

i am using trigger to auto insert new row for every month

```
DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER update_students_attendance
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `students_attendance` FOR EACH ROW
  begin
      DECLARE new_month TINYINT;
      SET new_month = (SELECT month FROM students_attendance WHERE student_id = NEW.student_id AND month = NEW.month);
      IF new_month is NULL OR new_month = ''
      THEN
          INSERT INTO students_attendance (student_id, month) VALUES (NEW.student_id, NEW.month);
      END IF;
  END;
  $$
DELIMITER ;
```

but when i use below update statement, it doesnt insert any row ...

```
UPDATE students_attendance set `w1` = 'Absent' where `student_id` = '1' and `month` = '1'
```

can anyone help me ??

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: @P.Salmon , No , it return - 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0050 seconds.)

Comment: Even if your logic was correct you would get a "ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'students_attendance' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger." on execution. (you should google this for more information)

Answer (score -1):

```
DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER update_students_attendance
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `students_attendance` FOR EACH ROW
  begin
      DECLARE new_month TINYINT;
      (SELECT month into new_month FROM students_attendance WHERE student_id = NEW.student_id AND month = NEW.month);
      IF new_month is NULL OR new_month = ''
      THEN
          INSERT INTO students_attendance (student_id, month) VALUES (NEW.student_id, NEW.month);
      END IF;
  END;
  $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Try above code.

Answer (score -1):

Please check below mentioned trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER update_students_attendance
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `students_attendance` FOR EACH ROW
  begin
      DECLARE new_month TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
      SELECT month into new_month FROM students_attendance WHERE student_id = NEW.student_id AND month = NEW.month;
      IF new_month is NULL OR new_month < 1 THEN 
          INSERT INTO students_attendance (student_id, month) VALUES (NEW.student_id, NEW.month);
      END IF;
  END;
  $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: same thing as i wrote, if row wont exist than mysql return can be compared with null and empty string or you can use 1, but stll not working

Answer (score -2):

```
UPDATE students_attendance SET w1='Absent' WHERE student_id='1' AND month='1'
```

Comment: this is the same thing i  wrote above. capitalization wont affect

Comment: Not the capitalization . The quotes.

Comment: dude, we can use back-quote around table or column name, problem is in trigger not in this update query